# Javascript based Tabs - on page reload data is lost

Tags: javascript

I am using a Tab based layout, which has 5 Steps with different input fields for each step.
and if user on step 4 page reloads then start the complete process from step1 agaig. Is there any possibility to remain on step 4 after reploading the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use localStorage to store your information collected so far. If a reload happens, first check, whether any data has already been entered and if so fill in the appropriate elements and redirect the user to the first "unfinished" tab.

[localStorage Docu @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)